# Persistent comment

Tags: bug, comment-replies

The site went offline some time ago, and right before it did, I have received a comment reply.

I could only read that comment reply after the site came back online. But now it won't go away, even though the thread in which the comment exists was deleted (by the owner).

This means that whenever I open a new page (or even hit refresh) the red mark notifying me of a comment reply is back, with the same comment.

[Technical details: Arch Linux, 64bit, Firefox 29.0.1]

---

Related Meta.SE threads:

1. [For crying out loud, I've read that message already](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233448/for-crying-out-loud-ive-read-that-message-already)
2. [Added rep notification isn't going away after clicking it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233447/added-rep-notification-isnt-going-away-after-clicking-it)

Comment: The items in the black bar do not get cleared for me. I click on them, read the item and click it away, then the next time I refresh the page, they're back. I am also using Firefox 29.0.1, but on MacOS X. I wouldn't mind it if the +10 would keep adding to my rep ;-)

Comment: Same here. That damned moderator inbox won't stay grey!

Comment: And in fact I don't even get notified of new things! It still shows "1". :(

Comment: Now you know exactly how Phil Connors felt. (same here btw).

Comment: In situations like this, the first thing I'll try is to clear the cache of my browser.

Comment: Mine is always grey, even when I've been pinged.

Comment: @GitGud: That's a shame!